# Android one activity to to popup window

Tags: android

My requirement is : List all sales route & highlight default, It should be first option. If the salesperson select other option(not selected default), then popup window should come. The popup window contain one form,  it talk to DB.After submit the popup window form , it return previous screen , It need to allow to go other position.

See my code

This initial list Activity:

```
    ArrayList<Object> routeList = getWmRoute();
    ArrayList<String> routhPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<routeList.size();i++){
        routhPath.add(((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
    }

    ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,routhPath);
    setListAdapter(ad);
    final ListView list=getListView();
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setItemChecked(0,true);
    list.setSelection(0);
```

This is listener method

```
   @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(position !=0 ){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        int postion = position;
        String aString = Integer.toString(postion);
        bundle.putString("positon", aString);
        Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SalesRouteDevitionActivity.class);
        // startActivityForResult(showContent,0);
        startActivity(showContent);

    }
}
```

This is my SalesRouteDevitionActivity class

```
   array_spinner=new String[2];
    array_spinner[0]="Rain";
    array_spinner[1]="Floods";
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    param1 = bundle.getString("param1");

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(SalesRouteDevitionActivity.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SalesRouteActivity.class);

             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("position", param1);
             Intent mIntent = new Intent();
             mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
             setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
             finish();
            startActivity(showContent);


         }
     });
```

This is my manifest file

```
  <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name=".SalesRouteDevitionActivity"
              android:label="Sales Route Diviation">
    </activity>
```

After finish pop window work , how we can go to previous activity that particular place?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from wherever you start the popup window call it using intent throught call this startActivityForResult(your_intent,requestCode)

it will start the activity and in the popup activity do like this way

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("position", param1);

Intent mIntent = new Intent();
mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
finish();
```

so the popup will finish his activity and go back to previous activity where it will invoked with the result

and in your activity override the onActivityResult like this way

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==1){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       else
          Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global variable for the position of the selected item. Then when you return to the previous activity, you call `listView1.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want listview focus on a position which is not default?If so, you only need return intent with position and at onActivityForResult() you set focus at that position.If you have any problems, please add my yahoo or skype:fsoft_duonghv and we discuss .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting a new activity for a popup window you can create a [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). You can call dismiss() to return your activity then.